Confidence interval for difference of means $\mu_1 - \mu_2$ with unknown variances $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ where $\sigma_1^2=4\sigma_2^2$.
I have to determine a (1-$\alpha$) confidence interval for $\mu_1 - \mu_2$ of the following independent variables:
$X_1,\dots , X_{n_1} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$
$Y_1,\dots , Y_{n_2} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_2^2)$
My course however, only saw the case where the variances are equal, yet in this excercise we have that $\sigma_1^2=4\sigma_2^2$ so I have no clue what to do. In the case where the variances are equal we can use the pooled variance to create such an interval, but in this case the variances differ by a factor of 4. I have done some searching online and noticed it can be done with the Welch's t-interval but there is no mention of that in our course so I don't think we are allowed to use it.

Given that $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{n_1}\overbrace{\sim}^{\text{i.i.d}}\mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$, $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_{n_2}\overbrace{\sim}^{\text{i.i.d}}\mathcal{N}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$, where $\sigma_1^2=4\sigma_2^2$, and $X_i$s are independent of $Y_i$s.
Sample means
$\displaystyle\overline{X}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}X_i}{n_1}\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_1,\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n_1}\right)$,
$\displaystyle\overline{Y}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_2}Y_i}{n_2}\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu_2,\frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2}\right)$
Therefore,
$\displaystyle\overline{X} -\overline{Y}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mu_1-\mu_2,\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2}\right)$
So,
$\displaystyle\dfrac{\overline{X} -\overline{Y}-(\mu_1-\mu_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2}}}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)$
Also,
$\displaystyle\dfrac{(n_1-1)S^2_1}{\sigma_1^2}=\dfrac{1}{\sigma_1^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n_1}(X_i-\overline{X})^2\sim\chi^2_{(n_1-1)}$ and $\displaystyle\dfrac{(n_2-1)S^2_2}{\sigma_2^2}=\dfrac{1}{\sigma_2^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n_2}(Y_i-\overline{Y})^2\sim\chi^2_{(n_2-1)}$
Therefore, $\displaystyle\dfrac{(n_1-1)S^2_1}{\sigma_1^2}+\dfrac{(n_2-1)S^2_2}{\sigma_2^2}\sim\chi^2_{(n_1+n_2-2)}$.
Consequently,
$\displaystyle\dfrac{\sqrt{n_1+n_2-2}\left(\dfrac{\overline{X} -\overline{Y}-(\mu_1-\mu_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_1^2}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2}}}\right)}{\sqrt{\dfrac{(n_1-1)S^2_1}{\sigma_1^2}+\dfrac{(n_2-1)S^2_2}{\sigma_2^2}}}\sim t_{n_1+n_2-2}$
Given that $\sigma_1^2=4\sigma^2_2$, we get
$\displaystyle\dfrac{\sqrt{n_1+n_2-2}\left(\dfrac{\overline{X} -\overline{Y}-(\mu_1-\mu_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{4\sigma_2^2}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{n_2}}}\right)}{\sqrt{\dfrac{(n_1-1)S^2_1}{4\sigma_2^2}+\dfrac{(n_2-1)S^2_2}{\sigma_2^2}}} =\displaystyle\dfrac{\sqrt{n_1+n_2-2}\left(\dfrac{\overline{X} -\overline{Y}-(\mu_1-\mu_2)}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{n_1}+\frac{1}{n_2}}}\right)}{\sqrt{\dfrac{(n_1-1)S^2_1}{4}+\dfrac{(n_2-1)S^2_2}{1}}} \sim t_{n_1+n_2-2}$
We can now use the above $t$-distribution to construct the $(1-\alpha)100\%$ confidence interval in the routine way.
